# Installing MySQL driver for Python on Mac

Tags: python, mysql, macports

I am running MAMP and Python as CGI. I want to connect MySQL. I tried MySQLDb by installing it with pip but it did not work and python could not locate MySQLDb at all.

Can you tell me how can I install it by using Macport provider I already have Apache,MySQL and Python 2.6 installed?

Thanks

**Update:**

Installing via pip gave following O/P:

> Downloading/unpacking mysql-python   Downloading
>   MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz (70Kb): 70Kb downloaded   Running setup.py
>   egg_info for package mysql-python
>       warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
>       warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
>       warning: no files found matching 'GPL' Installing collected packages: mysql-python   Running setup.py install for mysql-python
>       building '_mysql' extension
>       /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -pipe -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D_*version*_=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6
>   -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.o -g
>       In file included from _mysql.c:36:
>       /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/include/my_config.h:330:1: warning: "SIZEOF_SIZE_T" redefined
>       In file included from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:9,
>                        from pymemcompat.h:10,
>                        from _mysql.c:29:
>       /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pymacconfig.h:37:1:
>   warning: this is the location of the previous definition
>       In file included from _mysql.c:36:
>       /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/include/my_config.h:423:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
>       In file included from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
>                        from pymemcompat.h:10,
>                        from _mysql.c:29:
>       /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:808:1:
>   warning: this is the location of the previous definition
>       /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -L/opt/local/lib -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.o
>   -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -lz -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.so
>       warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
>       warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
>       warning: no files found matching 'GPL' Successfully installed mysql-python Cleaning

I am using the MySQL shipped with MAMP. I had also set PATH to Binary of MySQL within MAMP folder

**Another Update**

Turned out that Mysql-Python egg did not install at all in:

**/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages**

What am I missing?

Comment: You should consider updating to Python 2.7.

Comment: You should look in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ instead of /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages I think.